# How to get the array of RGB values for each pixel of the client area of a window

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, pixel

Is there a way to receive the colour values for each pixel in the client area of a window, with gdi?

Comment: Is this for one of your own windows or for somebody else's window? Generally speaking, you shouldn't be messing with somebody else's window. And since you drew your window yourself, you should already know what color it is.

Comment: for the window(s) of my own application... I'm using various functions to paint to the window, so I'd have to reverse engineer every one of those to find out what pixel has what colour... seems a little overkill

Comment: @xcrypt: Assuming the code that draws the window takes an HDC (or equivalent) as a parameter, just create a bitmap, select it into a memory DC, and then pass that as the target for drawing the window.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How would I do that exactly? I'm not really an expert with the GDI

Comment: @xcrypt: the details will depend on the rest of your code. I don't know enough about that to even make an intelligent guess about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comment by @JerryCoffin. Here's a simple example

```
hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);
hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
hOld = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDC, x, y, SRCCOPY);

// Clean up
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
```

You should have a bitmap object selected into memory DC for which you can use [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GDI function and then you can also extract the color values using `GetRValue()` , `GetGValue()` , and `GetBValue()` macros.

Comment: Note that this may not include all the pixels in your client area. For example, if another window is covering yours, those pixels will not be available (since they were never painted). Better would be to create the bitmap in a memory DC and then run your paint code directly into that memory DC. That way you get the bits at full fidelity with no clipping, and you avoid the large video readback expense.